# How to send client side javascript date in form that calls a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I use PHP to write date and time to a MySql table.  I want to write both the client Date time and the server date time.  I have the server date/time figured out with PHP, so I just need the client date/time stored in a PHP variable.  Thanks for any input.  I feel like I am real close.  One thing strange is in my isset.  I state if empty then the variable = "empty", but it never displays "empty" even with a strlen of 0

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>

    function ShowLocalDate()
            {
            var dNow = new Date();
            var localdate= (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

            document.getElementById("createdAt").innerHTML = localdate;
            }

    </script>


    </head>

    <body onload="ShowLocalDate()">

    <h1>Get current local Date in JQuery</h1>

    <label id="createdAt">This is current local Date Time in JQuery</label>

    <form action="date_time_tool2.php" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" id="createdAt" name="java_to_php" />

            <button type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>

    </form>

    </body>


    </body>
    </html>
```

date_time_tool2.php

```
<?php

$php_client_date  = isset($_REQUEST['java_to_php']) ? $_REQUEST['java_to_php'] : "empty";

echo 'Date = ' . $php_client_date . ' length = ' . strlen($php_client_date);

?>
```

Comment: You do know that it's 2018 and Java != JavaScript right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`
So now your

```js
function ShowLocalDate()
            {
            var dNow = new Date();
            var localdate= (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

            document.getElementById("createdAtInput").value = localdate;
            // For JQuery you can use it like this
            
            $("#createdAtJquery").val(localdate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="ShowLocalDate()">

    <h1>Get current local Date in JQuery</h1>

    <label id="createdAt">This is current local Date Time in JQuery</label>

    <form action="date_time_tool2.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" id="createdAtInput" name="java_to_php" />
            <input type="text" id="createdAtJquery" name="java_to_php" />

            <button type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>

    </form>

    </body>
```

> I have changed the type from hidden to text for you to see. And the
>   important thing is you can not use the same id in your HTML more than
>   once.So please consider taking some javascript course as there are
>   millions of them and most being free.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have same id for the label and input, try the below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

function ShowLocalDate()
        {
        var dNow = new Date();
        var localdate= (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

        document.getElementById("createdAtLabel").innerHTML = localdate;
        document.getElementById("createdAt").value = localdate;
        }

</script>


</head>

<body onload="ShowLocalDate()">

<h1>Get current local Date in JQuery</h1>

<label id="createdAtLabel">This is current local Date Time in JQuery</label>

<form action="date_time_tool2.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="createdAt" name="java_to_php" />

        <button type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>

</form>

</body>


</body>
</html>
```